# Forcing request from local node

Tags: cassandra, datastax

Can I force a query to fetch from local itself. WE have two data centers with replication factor 3 and 3 and i want to see the replicaiton is done properly or not 1) across nodes and 2 ) across data centers.  Can i force the query to check only from a particular node and see if data is present in that node?  I know getendpoints will fetch if i give ids but if want to check table updates in general and see if the data is being replicated or not how can i do this?  APart from local_quorum we have any other option?  Thanks

Comment: Yes. I tried CL one. but it is showing the data present is present in both nodes. I am unable to confirm it is present in local nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I can understand why someone might want to do this (sanity check), and I'll put some instructions on how to do this below. However firstly, it's not really necessary; The reason is because Cassandra is a distributed system, under normal circumstances its not necessary to check data is on a given node, the replication will place a given row on a given node according to where the snitch determines placement. So for a given replication factor like DC1:3 and DC2:3 a row may be on *any* 3 nodes in each DC. As long as you can query the *cluster as a whole* or *each DC* and get the right results then you know that your replication is working ok.

Having said that, here is how you find a key, the caveat is it has to be flushed to disc (you might need to invoke a [nodetool flush](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsFlush.htmlhttps://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsFlush.html)). It may seem convoluted but this is how you trace it to a sstable so you may find this useful to know:

1. Use [nodetool getendpoints](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsGetEndPoints.html) to locate the nodes the key is on
2. Use [nodetool getsstables](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/tools/toolsGetSstables.html) to find the sstables the key is present in
3. Locate the file on disc and then use [sstable2json](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/toolsSStable2json_t.html) to view the contents of the table, or use [sstablekeys](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/tools/toolsSStabkeys_t.html) to just view the keys

**Note: the sstable2json tools are only listed under Cassandra 1.2 docs but they should still be present in 2.1, at least I verified they are and have used them in DSE4.7 and 4.8.**